# Can firebase be used to load a JAR file and provide web service for the functions in it?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Can someone please provide me direction on how this can be achieved?

I'm a legacy Android developer and having hard time of how firebase can be used to provide a web service to the Android app using my JAR file hosted on server.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

I would love if some user allows to personal message them. I need some mentoring on firebase.

Comment: I think you can't ask for mentoring here. You should show you've put some effort. Here are some tips about asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: *firebase here* Firebase currently offers no way to run your code on our back-end. We're looking into extending [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) for use with some of our features (mostly the realtime database), but have nothing to announce at this time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373221/firebase-aftersave-function-like-parse-com