# Firebase database backend logic

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, backend

I have a firebase database and i need some values of each user to be incremented every two hours. How to do that? How can i add my own backend logic to the existing firebase backend logic?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373221/firebase-aftersave-function-like-parse-com/35373622#35373622